# Клик на radio кнопку с помощью python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

хочу нажать на радио кнопку c помощью selenium, которая даст возможность создать свой собственный email. Я  посмотрел на многих сайтах с такими же вопросами и там все решалось либо через xpath либо через css. Но я не смог найти css и вообще указание на то, что это радиобаттон(<input type='radio'...), кроме role='radio'.  По идее я тут еще должен прикрепить свои попытки реализовать клик, но простите, их просто нет, я без идей что тут можно сделать. Надеюсь на помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]